# Linear regression: confidence interval

Tags: linear-regression, confidence-interval

How to compute the confidence interval of a linear regression, please?

I found:
$$ V = a \pm da $$
$$ da = t(percentile, N-2) . \sigma $$
$$\sigma = a \sqrt{ \frac{1/R^2 - 1}{N-2}} $$

Are these formulas correct?

I have plotted data using matlab.
The **polyval** function outputs the delta is proportional to the confidence interval:
$$ CI = k \; Delta $$
This coefficient $k$ can be calculated with the *t-distribution* (tinv? function on Matlab + Statistical Toolbox).
For the moment, I used $k=1.96$ because I'm not really sure about the value to choose.

[image: Linear regression example]

From https://www.real-statistics.com/regression/confidence-and-prediction-intervals/:
[image: Formula]

Here is the matlab code to generate the figure:

```
%%
% fake data

n=10; %n points

xs = linspace(0,50,n);
ys = 3 * xs + 2;

noise = 15*randn(1, n); %generate noise    
ys = ys + noise;   %add noise


%%
[p, S] = polyfit(xs,ys,1);
[yhat, delta] = polyval(p, xs, S); 

% residues
residues = yhat - ys;
squarredResidues = residues.^2;
stdResidues = std(residues);

k=1.96; % student's t-distribution => HOW?
yhatmin = yhat - k*delta;
yhatmax = yhat + k*delta;

% plot data
figure(1); clf

plot(xs, ys, 'kx'); hold on;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');

plot(xs, yhat, 'b-');
plot(xs, yhatmin, 'r--');
plot(xs, yhatmax, 'r--');
```

Comment: Although not in the question, you could also perform a t confidence interval for the slope of the population regression line.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, If I'm not wrong... the red curves on my chart are the results of all generated lines with a slope between [slopeMin, slopeMax] and [interceptMin, interceptMax].

Comment: There are a few inference conditions, but the confidence interval for $\beta$= the slope of the regression line relating $y$ to $x$ in the given population is $b\pm t^*\text{SE}_b=b\pm t^*\frac{s}{s_x\sqrt{n-1}}$. Here,  $s$ is the standard error of the residuals $y-\hat y$

Comment: @TymaGaidash and $s_z = stdev(y-\bar{y})$ ? Could you tell me more about the t value, please? I read $t_{\alpha/2}$, if the confidence is 0.95, $\alpha=0.05$ or $0.95$?

Comment: For a two tailed significance test, $C+\alpha=1$ with $C$ being the confidence level, so $\alpha=0.05$ for a significance test giving the same conclusion as the confidence interval. $s_x$ is the standard deviation of the independent variable while $s$ is the standard deviation of the residuals. Where is $s_z$ from? I did not see “$t_\frac\alpha2$“ in your question nor in the real-statistics link; where is it from?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. I found some references here:  https://www.real-statistics.com/regression/confidence-and-prediction-intervals/